# Qt C++ Drawing and Animation

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, drawing

I am a newbie to Qt. And I have this problem for which I want to have a method to solve.
I want to draw a road network, that remains static throughout the execution of the program. On this road network, I then want to draw a car (a simple circle or rectangle is enough) that moves on this road network from a starting point to finish.

I started with Drawing on a widget. I drew roads (using polygons) and so far it looks okay.

Q1) How can I now draw an other object (car) that can move?

I see I need to repaint. i.e. paint function that I defined in my widget will be called again and again based on some timer I set for repainting. When this event is received the position of my car changes. And the complete scene is redrawn. Am I correct?

Q2) How can I treat road network as a separate element and the car as separate element? i.e. like two separate widgets such that I only send repaint event to my (e.g. car class)

Q3) I am using QPainter and QWidget classes. Is it better to do this with QGraphicsScene? Is there any tutorial or sample code I can see?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitelly use `QGraphicsScene` where you will put `QGraphicsObject` onto. This will allow you to have greator control on how things should be painted.

You can create custom `QGraphicsObject` and write `paint` method which will define how your object should be painted - here you can implement behaviour for drawing cars or road network. As for tutorial, browse those which are included in QtCreator, you will find.

Answer (score 0):

Use `QGraphicsScene` and `QGraphicsView` to display the picture. It performs all the drawing and repainting automatically. It's much more convenient (and in some case more efficient) than custom drawing over widgets. Also it treats your objects separately, you can move them independently.

Use `QGraphicsScene::addPolygon` and similar methods to add roads. Use `QGraphicsScene::addPixmap` to add the car. Use `QGraphicsItemAnimation` to animate the car.

Documentation (examples included):

- [QGraphicsItemAnimation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitemanimation.html)
- [Graphics View Framework](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html)
- [Animation Framework Examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-animation.html)